# How to SET multiple user variables inside IF on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where I want to set multiple variables when a condition mets.

```
IF(expr1, @reading:=0 and @prevdate:=@stepdate, @reading:=@reading)
```

as you see I want to set `@reading:=0 and @prevdate:=@stepdate` but this does not work.

how can I set multiple user-variables inside the `true` or `false` node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**
The `AND` does short circuit evaluation.
The `@reading:= 0` evaluates to 0, which is false.

`0 and x` is always 0, so MySQL does not bother to evaluate x.
`OR` suffers from the same problem: `1 OR x` is alway true.
This is a way to speed things up by stopping as soon as the outcome if known.

**Solution**
Change it to `@reading:= 0 XOR @prevdate:= @stepdate`

This will solve your problem, because XOR does not suffer from short-circuit evaluation.

`1 XOR x` can be anything as well as `0 XOR x`.